# Factorization of product distribution

Tags: regression, probability, heteroscedasticity, error, joint-distribution

I would like to obtain a factorization of the probability distribution of a random variable $Z$ which is the product of two independent random variables $\delta=\varepsilon X$ where $\varepsilon \sim N(0,1)$, the distribution of $X$ is arbitrary, and $ \varepsilon \mathrel{\unicode{x2AEB}} X$ ($ \varepsilon$ is independent of  $X$).

The underlying motivation is that I want to study a regression model with heteroskedastic composite error term, $\delta=\varepsilon X$, in which that composite error term fulfills $ \varepsilon \mathrel{\unicode{x2AEB}} X$:

$$ y=h(x)+\delta$$

with $h()$ a linear function of $x$.

Is it possible to define $$f_\delta(\varepsilon x) = f_{\varepsilon}(y-h(x)) \times f_{X}(y-h(x))$$ where $f$ denotes density functions and which uses the independence assumption $ \varepsilon \mathrel{\unicode{x2AEB}} X$?

One can find a lot of material on the factorization of a joint probability distribution of two random variables, eg. $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X}(x) \times f_{Y}(y)$, however not on the factorization of a product distribution.

Comment: Mathematically, the equation following "is it possible to define" is nonsensical, because $f$ must be a function of *one* variable but you refer to two variables "$x$" and "$y$".  Please, therefore, explain what you mean by "factorization."